# How to check a string contains another string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, linq

I i have string of numbers separated by commas ,How to check if another string contained in that string .

For example :

If i have a string :

```
67,782,452,67632,9,155,323
```

How to check that `155` is in the previous string using linq ?

Comment: Is LINQ an absolute requirement?

Comment: @PaoloTedesco No , but i want to know how to do that through `linq`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you want to check if one of the items in the string is your given string. I would split the string first by the delimiter `,`, then use `Contains` or `Any`:

```
string[] items = "67,782,452,67632,9,155,323".Split(',');
bool contains = items.Contains("155");
contains = items.Any(i => i == "155");
```

The problem with the `Contains`-check on the string is that also "1550" would contain "155".

Comment: is `Any` give the exact not like `Contains` ??

Comment: i mean u use `Contains` then `Any` ?!

Comment: @just_name: that's just to demonstrate both ways. `Enumerable.Any` is more flexible since you could use any code here. `Contains` must be used with the same type as the array and it used the default equality check. But `Conatains` is more readable and works also here.

Comment: +1 *Contains-check on the string is that also "1550" would contain "155"*

Answer (score 3):

For e.g. using `String.Contains` or `Any` (you can use string.Contains in your linq query)

```
string a = "67,782,452,67632,9,155,323";
var splitted = a.Split(',');
if(splitted.Any(x=> x == "155"))
{
 ...
}
```

or

```
if(splitted.Contains("155"))
{
 ...
}
```

or ugly one-liner

```
var contains = a.Split(',').Any(x=>x=="155");
```

Comment: This would return true also if the string was for example "1,1550,2"

Comment: @PaoloTedesco good point, edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

Split the string and then check the resulting array:

```
string input = "67,782,452,67632,9,155,323";
string[] values = input.Split(',');
bool contained = values.Contains("155");
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Linq:

```
var str = "67,782,452,67632,9,155,323";
var arr = str.Split(',');

var isInString = arr.Any(x => x == "155");
```